# Xpath 1.0 Mysql issue

Tags: mysql, xpath

I have this sample xml

```xml
<ProductSaleItem>
  <ItemReference>100</ItemReference>
  <Discount>
    <Modifier>1</Modifier>
  </Discount>
</ProductSaleItem>
<ProductSaleItem>
  <ItemReference>101</ItemReference>
  <Discount>
    <Modifier>1</Modifier>
  </Discount>
  <Discount>
    <Modifier>2</Modifier>
  </Discount>
</ProductSaleItem>
<ProductSaleItem>
  <ItemReference>102</ItemReference>
</ProductSaleItem>
```

and this xpath

```xml
//ProductSaleItem[Discount/Modifier]/ItemReference
```

i am hoping to get

```
100 101
```

but all i get is

```
100
```

It seems the two Discount is stopping the node from being included
How do i fix my Predicate please?

This is in mysql so uses xpath 1.0

```sql
    select extractvalue( "<ProductSaleItem><ItemReference>100</ItemReference><Discount>                    <Modifier>1</Modifier></Discount></ProductSaleItem><ProductSaleItem>        <ItemReference>101</ItemReference><Discount><Modifier>1</Modifier></Discount>
<Discount><Modifier>2</Modifier></Discount></ProductSaleItem><ProductSaleItem>
<ItemReference>102</ItemReference</ProductSaleItem>","//ProductSaleItem[*/Modifier]/ItemReference") bob;
```

I have tried online xpath parsers and some use xpath 2.0 which seems to work but mysql refuses to work.

Answer (score 1):

In the end I used

//ProductSaleItem/Discount/Modifier/../../ItemReference

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

According to [Mysql docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/xml-functions.html) `extractvalue()` returns the first node

> If multiple matches are found, the content of the first child text node of each matching element is returned (in the order matched) as a single, space-delimited string.

As suggested in the docs an iteration should be made (stored proc or similar)

```
WHILE i < 4 DO
  SELECT xml, i, ExtractValue(xml, '//a[$i]');
  SET i = i+1;
END WHILE;
```

May be getting the `Modifier`value could help as follows

```
select extractvalue( "<ProductSaleItem>
  <ItemReference>100</ItemReference>
  <Discount><Modifier>1</Modifier></Discount>
</ProductSaleItem>
<ProductSaleItem>
  <ItemReference>101</ItemReference>
  <Discount><Modifier>1</Modifier></Discount>
  <Discount><Modifier>2</Modifier></Discount>
</ProductSaleItem>
<ProductSaleItem>
  <ItemReference>102</ItemReference>
</ProductSaleItem>","//ItemReference") bob,
extractvalue( "<ProductSaleItem><ItemReference>100</ItemReference><Discount>                    <Modifier>1</Modifier></Discount></ProductSaleItem><ProductSaleItem>        <ItemReference>101</ItemReference><Discount><Modifier>1</Modifier></Discount>
<Discount><Modifier>2</Modifier></Discount></ProductSaleItem><ProductSaleItem>
<ItemReference>102</ItemReference></ProductSaleItem>","//ProductSaleItem/Discount[1]/Modifier") alice;
```

Output:

```
+-------------+-------+
| bob         | alice |
+-------------+-------+
| 100 101 102 | 1 1   |
+-------------+-------+
```

Comment: I ended up using //ProductSaleItem/Discount/Modifier/../../ItemReference

Comment: @Guy you can add that as an answer so other can easily find it. It's ok to answer own questions on SO